# How do I loop through characters with char*'s in C?

Tags: c, stack, calculator

I'm trying to create a Calculator in C. I'm positive that my parameter of **(char* String)** in my eval function is correct but I don't really understand why or how to use it properly. My eval function will be given input of math expressions in postfix notation. So here is my code so far and essentially I am trying to take in a String, push all the numbers into a string stack and then if a operator is found, pop two 'strings' off the string stack, convert those strings into ints (which is another thing I'm unsure of how to do), do calculation, push result onto int stack. After all of input has been searched through, loop through the int stack and add all of the ints. Here is my code:(ignore includes)  /*

```
int eval(char* String);   //implicit declarations
int bourneLongPush(int);
char* bournePop(void);
int bournePush(char *string);
int bourneLongPop(void);
int bourneGetLongStackSize(void);

int eval(char* String)
{
    int result = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
    char* endptr;

    while(String[index] != '\0'){                      //while our     String pointer is not equal to null,
        if(strtoimax(String, &endptr, 10) == NULL){    //if the character isn't a number,
            switch(String[index]){                     //switch on the operator
            case "+":  
                arg2 = bournePop();
                arg1 = bournePop();//*** how do I change char*'s to ints?
                bourneLongPush(arg2+arg1);
                break;
            case "-":
                arg2 = bournePop();
                arg1 = bournePop();
                bourneLongPush(arg2-arg1);
                break;
            case "/":
                arg2 = bournePop();
                arg1 = bournePop();
                bourneLongPush(arg2/arg1);
                break;
            case "*":
                arg2 = bournePop();
                arg1 = bournePop();
                bourneLongPush(arg2*arg1);
                break;
            case ">":
                arg2 = bournePop();
                arg1 = bournePop();
                bourneLongPush(arg2>>arg1);
                break;
            case "<":
                arg2 = bournePop();
                arg1 = bournePop();
                bourneLongPush(arg2<<arg1);
                break;
            case "^":
                arg2 = bournePop();
                arg1 = bournePop();
                bourneLongPush(pow(arg2, arg1));
                break;
            case "|":
                arg2 = bournePop();
                arg1 = bournePop();
                bourneLongPush(arg2|arg1);
                break;
            case "&":
                arg2 = bournePop();
                arg1 = bournePop();
                bourneLongPush(arg2&arg1);
                break;
            case "%":   
                arg2 = bournePop();
                arg1 = bournePop();
                bourneLongPush(arg2%arg1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        else{                                //a number was found
        int check = bournePush(String[index]);//push the number into string stack
            if(check == 1)
            {
                //error in push due to size
            }
        }
    index++;
    }
}
//Our input was read in as null so no more input needs to be read
    for(int j = 0; j<(int)bourneGetLongStackSize; j++)
    {
        int num = bourneLongPop();
        result += num;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can't you move the `arg2 = bournePop(); arg1 = bournePop();` to before the `switch` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I am suggesting that instead of pushing all the characters into the stack and then later converting them to integers and applying the operator, why don't we convert them to integers before pushing them into stack and then apply the operator.

So, your `else` condition in the loop shall look something like this ::

```
int num = 0;
while() {
    if(the character isn't a number) { //I do not exactly understand the condition you used here, but I hope you have got it figured
        bournePush(num);
        num = 0;
        switch(String[index]) {
        ...
        ...
        //remains same
        }
    }
    else {
        convertToNum(num, string[index]);
    }
}
```

Here I use `num` to store the value of number currently in string, so say if I encounter `123` in the string I will store `int 123` in `num` using the `convertToNum` function, so when I hit an operator I just push the complete `num` in the stack and re-initialize it to `0` so that I can use it for storing the next number.

And this is what `convertToNum` looks like ::

```
void convertToNum(int &num, char digit) {
    int numDigit = digit - '0';
    num = num*10 + numDigit;
}
```

Well this will answer your question on how to convert the chars to integer. Here I pass `num` by reference so that any changes that I make in `converToNum` are also seen in `main`. Then in `numDigit` I subtract the `char` `0` from `digit` this will subtract the ASCII value of `char 0` from `char digit` and will give us the value of the integer represented by that character. Then I do a simple multiplication with `10` and add the next digit, just simple maths.

Moreover, this very much simplifies the `bournePop` and `borneLongPop` function, since now your stack is only integers so, you don't need to have to separate functions and now you just pop one value from the stack and use it with the operators inside your `switch`.

I hope this helps!

**EDIT ::**

I am assuming that your postfix string has spaces in between to signify separate numbers, so you might actually have a string like this ::

> 123 456 +

So, the above code will actually fail since, after `456` it will encounter space on which it will enter the `if` condition and push `456` into stack and then when it will hit `+` it will push `0` into stack and then apply the `+` on `0 and 456` which is wrong, so we shall `bournePush` the `num` in the stack only when we encounter space. So your final code shall look like this ::

```
int num = 0;
while() {
    if(the character isn't a number) { //I do not exactly understand the condition you used here, but I hope you have got it figured
        if(String[index] == ' ') {
            bournePush(num);
            num = 0;
        } else {
            switch(String[index]) {
            ...
            ...
            //remains same
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        convertToNum(num, string[index]);
    }
}
```

Moreover I don't exactly think that your `switch` will work, because when you write `switch(String[index])` you have defined a `switch` for `char` when you write `case "+"` you are defining the case condition as a string which shall give a compilation error, I believe. So, all your `case` shall be changed like this `case '+'`, this will work.

Moreover a simpler way to check if a character is a number or not would be this::

```
int checkNum(char a) {
    if(a >= '0' && a <= '9')
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

This check if `a` is between `0` and `9` and returns `0`(false) and `1`(true) otherwise, just suggesting!

Answer (score 1):

1) `if(strtoimax(String, &endptr, 10) == NULL){` is not a good test to see if the conversion worked.

```
intmax_t value = strtoimax(String, &endptr, 10);
if (endptr != String) {
  // endptr now points to the next part of the string to parse
  ConversionWorked(value);
} else
  ConversionFailed();
}
```

Code could clear `errno` to detect overflow

```
errno = 0;
intmax_t = value = strtoimax(String, &endptr, 10);
if (endptr != String) {
  if (errno) ConversionOverflowed(value)
  else ConversionWorked(value);
} else
  ConversionFailed();
}
```

2) Wrong `switch()` usage

```
switch(String[index]) {
  // case "+": 
  case '+': // String[index] is a `char`, not a string
```

3) Likely other issues like `bournePush()` - but need to see unposted code to resolve..